# Webbrowser TypeError in Python

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to use `webbrowser.open` to send an email using the default mail client. My code looks like this:

```
mailto = "mailto:me@bla.com?subject=blabla&body=blabla"
webbrowser.open(mailto)
```

Although the mail client (Outlook) opens normally, I keep getting the following `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: open() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

I tried to use something like `webbrowser.open(mailto,1)` but the result is still the same.
Why could this happen?

Comment: To really get straight to the point, don't say "I'll get straight to the point", just get to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the webbrowser.open, mailto is 1 argument no matter what value it is. So you need to check again where the troublesome open invoking belongs to.

Comment: Hey,thanks for the answer.There is no other open in the code,this is the only one.